# Get content-length from a URL which redirects to itself

Tags: redirect, header, http-content-length

I want to get content-length from a URL that it sends me this header:

> HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently Date: Sun, 01 Jan 2012 09:34:44 GMT Server: Apache Location: https://www.sugarsync.com, www.sugarsync.com/pf/D6304231_0192919_76577 Keep-Alive: timeout=300, max=9793 Connection: Keep-Alive Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

The problem is that the original URL is the same new URL that in this header is sent! In other words: I get the headers from URL: https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D6304231_0192919_76577 and in headers that I get, it redirects to the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't seem to have that problem with the URL you provided:

```
C:\Users\rleahy>openssl s_client -quiet -connect sugarsync.com:443
Loading 'screen' into random state - done
depth=1 /C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certificates
.godaddy.com/repository/CN=Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority/serialNumber=
07969287
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
HEAD /pf/D6304231_0192919_76577 HTTP/1.1
host:www.sugarsync.com

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 01 Jan 2012 10:16:13 GMT
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=22C35505626E63560F5F00BDE86BD458; Path=/; Secure
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Algorithms(01).rar"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Etag: file_1319015834000
Last-Modified: Wed, 19 Oct 2011 09:17:14 GMT
Content-Length: 468987
Content-Type: application/x-download
Set-Cookie: NSC_wt_xxx.tvhbstzod.dpn_443=ffffffff090d78d545525d5f4f58455e445a4a4
2378b;path=/;secure;httponly
```

Are you sure you're not connecting with HTTP rather than HTTPS?  Connecting with HTTP does indeed give a 301 (asking you -- in effect -- to connect using HTTPS).